# LDAP query limitation

Tags: ldap, openldap, spring-ldap, ldap-query, spring-security-ldap

I am trying to write a ldap query which returns around 10000 users. But as far as the current api is concerned only 1500 is returned as search results.
I am not sure how to fix this. Is there a way where the api can handle around 10000 users as the search response.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What APIs are you using ? Show some code.

Comment: Its also possible that the search result size limit set on you LDAP server is 1500. Eg: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/820-2767/nssizelimit-5dsat/index.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two primary factors that would limit the search result count.

The Server Side [sizeLimit](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/SizeLimit) and the Client Side [SearchRequest](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/SearchRequest) sizelimit.

You maybe able to bypass the Server Side [sizeLimit](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/SizeLimit) by using the 
[Simple Paged Results Control](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Simple%20Paged%20Results%20Control)

For the Client Side [SearchRequest](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/SearchRequest) sizelimit, is adjusted on the client making the request where a value of "0" (Zero) is unlimited.